# Find $x$-coordinate of $Q$ from intersection of curve $y=ax^3$ and its tangent line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, cubics, tangent-line

> Let $a$ and $t$ be positive real numbers. Let $\ell$ be the tangent to the graph $C$ of $y=ax^3$ at a point $P$ $(t,at^3)$, and let $Q$ be the point at which $\ell$ intersects the curve $C$ again. Further, let $p$ be the line passing though the point $P$ parallel to the $x$-axis; let $q$ be the line passing through the point $Q$ parallel to the $y$-axis; let $R$ be the point of intersection of $p$ and $q$. $x$-coordinate of $Q$ is in the form $-Et$. Find $E$.

**My attempt:**
We obtained the equation of the tangent $\ell$ from the slope $y'=2at^3$ at point $P$, then

$y=3at^2x-2at^3$

To find $x$-coordinate, we know that $Q$ is a point at which $\ell$ intersects the curve $C$, then

Equation of curve C = Equation of tangent line

$ax^3=3at^2x-2at^3$

$x^3-3t^2x+2t^3=0$

Now I do not know how I could continue from here, could you please hint me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your cubic equation $x^3 - 3t^2x+2t^3 = 0$, and you know that $x = t$ is a solution, because the line intersects the curve there. In fact, you know that $x = t$ is a *double* solution, because the line is *tangent* to the curve there.

Which is to say that $(x-t)^2 = x^2 - 2tx + t^2$ is a factor of $x^3-3t^2x+2t^3$. So you can perform the polynomial division $(x^3-3t^2x+2t^3):(x^2-2tx+t^2)$ to get the final factor of $x^3-3t^2x+2t^3$, which also gives you the final root of the cubic equation.

Or you could use Vieta's formulas: We see that the product of the roots is $-2t^3$ (the constant term, with a negative sign because we have an odd degree polynomial), and we know that two of the roots are $t$ and $t$. That should make it rather obvious what the third root is.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Next time, please tell me about minor typos in a comment rather than fixing it yourself. Your edit removed the second half of my last paragraph. Not really all that bad this time, but it's not the first time edits done by others revert larger revisions that I've done (or am in the process of doing), and it's annoying every time.

Comment: I just did not want that you'll get down-voting. But if you say...

Answer (score 1):

Now, write
$$x^3-3t^2x+2t^3=x^3-2tx^2+t^2x+2tx^2-4t^2x+2t^3=(x-t)^2(x+2t).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: What is the general form you are using to factorize into $(x-t)^2(x+2t)$?

Comment: @Trey Anupong Yes of course. It works for all $a\neq0.$